# Connect to SQL Server 2005 from a windows mobile

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, windows-mobile-6

I am new to this site, hope that you won't laugh at my problem.

I have a new type of project for me to build, I need to write an app for a motorola symbol mc9090 barcode scanner running Windows Mobile 6. I need to connect from this app to a SQL Server 2005 database. Can I connect with an ado connection like the one below? The port is open. I use Windows classic emulator for debugging but it crashes at `myconn.open()`.

Thank you very much for your answers.

```
SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(@" Data Source=***.***.0.***,1443;Initial Catalog=test_database;User ID=****ica;Password=********;");

try
{
    myConn.Open();

    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select * from test_table where id = 1", myConn);

    SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        MessageBox.Show(reader[0].ToString() + "\t" + reader[1].ToString());
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{ 
    myConn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem in my case was the virtual pc, the emulator had problems connecting to the internet.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @GregS actually it seems that this was the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect to SQL Server directly from Windows Phone. You have to use Web API or Webservices to achieve this.

Windows Phone ==> Web API ==> Database

If your app needs to work offline, you have to use local databases.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202860(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: hello, but for me it works, i have used this info: https://sampath.wordpress.com/2007/03/20/connecting-to-sql-server-express-from-a-pocket-pc-application/ I managed to make it work from the emulator why wouldn't work from the device itself? again thank you

Comment: I thought you were looking for windows phone, not windows mobile. it was a confusion.

Comment: no problem, what i use is a motorola mc9090 barcode scanner running windows mobile 6. if anyone else come across this problem they should now to use the ip and opened port as data source in connection string.